# How to use "adduser" to create a user with an extra field, like Work Phone number?

Tags: linux, bash

I need to use `adduser` to add a user from the command line. Currently, I am doing

```
sudo adduser -g someGroup -c "John Doe" dojohn
```

but I'd like to have the command also include a "Work Phone number" like `777 222 1342`. 
I'm sure it has something to do with `adduser.conf`, but have not been able to find more information about it online.

*If relevant:

OS: Ubuntu Linux, Shell: bash

User: John Doe, username: dojohn, Work Phone Number: 777 222 1342*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment field in linux is traditionally split like this:

real name,room number,work phone,home phone,other

So you can populate these with the -c command:

```
sudo adduser -g someGroup -c "John Doe,,777 222 1342" dojohn
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no field in the passwd or shadow authdbs for anything other than the "comment" provided with `-c`, and there is no way for `useradd` to provide additional information for an authdb that *does* have such a field (e.g. LDAP). You will need to use both a different authdb and a different tool in order to provide such information in a meaningful manner.